# QGIS Load WFS everytime different Output

Tags: qgis, wfs, getfeature

I want to load a WFS in QGIS and execute some queries. I tried different versions of QGIS.

- QGIS 2.18 number of objects: 160036 (first query)
- QGIS 2.18 number of objects: 80018 (second query)
- QGIS 3.2.0 number of objects: 81103
- QGIS 3.4.5 number of objects: 80018

To check the correct number of objects I load the WFS in FME and get 80018.

I tried other WFS Clients and there I get in every version the correct number of objects.

Unfortunately I can´t give you the WFS because the access is restricted.

Does anyone have an idea why each version spends a different number of objects and why reloading in the same version will dump different objects?

Comment: do you use the same bounding box each time?

Comment: Yes, I use for every query the same settings